# How to use TryParse

Tags: c#, visual-c++, c++-cli, tryparse

when I try to use TryParse, its not working...

```
MyTxtBxStr="Something";
System::Decimal MyNumber1=0;
if (!Decimal::TryParse(MyTxtBxStr, MyNumber1)){
     MessageBox.Show("Invalid Value....Try Again");
}
```

It's giving the error like Syntax error C2143 missing ';' before '.'

Comment: using C# or Visual-C++?

Comment: `System::Decimal` - that is not C# IMO...

Comment: Combining C++ with C#?

Comment: Maybe you can ask Microsoft to release a `C+#` compiler for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's C++, you must write

```
MessageBox::Show("Invalid Value....Try Again");
```

Comment: Its my careless mistake, since wholeday bussy with codings...Thanks to RZLourenco, Thanks for your kind reply